# Working Around Multiple Exceptions

Tags: java, exception, try-catch-finally

I'm in a dire situation which is summed up by the following code.

```
try {
    dangerousCode();    // Declares `throws ExecutionException`
}
catch (ExecutionException ex) {
    handleIt();
    throw ex;
}
catch (RuntimeException ex) {
    handleIt();
    throw new ExecutionException(ex);
}
finally {
    notifyListeners();  // May throw RuntimeException!
}
```

I would like to stick to the contract of propagating a potential `ExecutionException` derived from the dangerous code - explicitly thrown, **or** wrapping a `RuntimeException`.

However, the listeners in the `finally` block *(which I don't control)* may throw **another** runtime exception.
Of course, I would also like to notify the client of this event.

**The dilemma:** I now have two exceptions on hands.

I could define my own exception type to wrap both exceptions thrown.

```
class MyExecutionException {
    Throwable getCause();
    Throwable getSecondCause();
}
```

I was just wondering, is there another way around this issue?

Comment: Since Java 7 you can use:

`} catch(ExecutionException | RuntimeException ex) {`

Comment: @Sergi I know, but then I would be wrapping an `ExecutionException`with another `ExecutionException`. That's the difference between both catch blocks.

Comment: If the client really has to know about both exceptions, you need something like your wrapper. The only other way i can think of would be if you know the client will have to do some extensive recovery work from your exception, and add some `callMeToNotifyAllClientsAfterRecoveryFromDangerousCode()` method that notifies listeners about whatever your client did to recover from the first exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was just wondering, is there another way around this issue?

Your idea is perfectly fine. Using own classes for `try-catch` nested in a `catch` or `finally` statement is a common practice. In larger applications such constructs are almost unavoidable.

Your class could look like this:

```
class MyExecutionException extends MyLogicException {
    //what happened in the first place
    Throwable getOriginException();

    // what have we tried?
    Throwable getRecoveryException();

     // more than 1 thing can happen in recovery, order is important, hence list
    List<Throwable> getAllExceptions(); 
}
```

Such approach lets you have all the information in one place and makes implementing a single place for exception handling and logging very easy. Just make sure you make your exception wrapper/container class as versatile as possible to suit your future needs.

Comment: I wasn't aware that it is a common practice. Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two methods `initCause()` and `getCause()`, which can wrap your exception:

```
Exception e = new Exception();
e.initCause(new Exception());
Throwable t = e.getCause(); //returns Throwable
```

Comment: The problem is that in this approach there never will be two (nor more) separate "branches" of exceptions - which should be the case for an exception occuring when trying to recover from another exception.